# How to fill data in a Word document from a Web based tool

Tags: javascript, java, ms-word

I've a sample Word document which will act as a template. I want to create a web based tool where I can insert in a form and the data from the form fields should get filled up in the Word document at their respective defined places. I also want the ability to insert images in the document.

So I want to know, is there any way of doing this, preferably using JavaScript or Java, or any other language?

Also, is there any open source solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache POI [(https://poi.apache.org/)](https://poi.apache.org/)

This should have been a simple google search.